# Net-SNMP Agent snmptrapd.conf examples

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu virtual machines to receive test traps to help me get a handle of SNMP. I'm looking for examples of snmptrapd.conf files to help me get a handle  of the software. I'm fairly new at using Ubuntu and SNMP so feel free to tell me anything I should probably know.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar when I started developing in SNMP, its a good path to go down. Make sure your network troubleshooting is good with virtual machines, VM tools like VirtualBox can disconnect while your doing something with SNMP. [net-snmp command line tuts](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials) are where I always end up, and I usually have to figure what each chunk of config does when things aren't working.

Often, you'll need to verify SNMP is communicating correctly. For that, there's nothing like Wireshark with the snmp filter. Later, when you want to automate or quickly script some SNMP stuff, Scapy can help with that and is a great library.

Start with SNMP v2c (packets are completely clear text and parsed by packet tools). Then go to V3 with no encryption. When things are working with that, then do v3 with encryption.